# Acer Aspire V3-571G BIOS password reset/remove

Tags: bios, passwords, reset

I had a clean Win8 install under Acer authorized service station for AspireV3-571G under warranty almost 1 year ago. They had changed the BIOS password without my knowledge. Now for dual-boot and many other purposes, I need to change the boot priority in firmware settings, but I can't enter the BIOS.

Comment: Have you tried taking it back to them or just asking them if there is a password that they reset the bios to? (ex: maybe they reset every computer's bios they work on to "12345" or something)

Comment: @blaine That is my last alternative as my laptop is out of warranty now, and they won't entertain any help/complaints without charging money. Moreover, I guess they have some company policy of not disclosing BIOS information/password.

Comment: Now _that_ is really annoying. I would like to find the solution also as my friend has an acer with a similar problem